# Query Cost best practice

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Suppose my select query has cost 100 and I have another way in which i am writing two queries which has cost (40 + 60). Both have same cost ultimately.

I want to know what is the most effective way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ignore cost. its not the starting place for tuning, its just an internal ranking used by Oracle to pick the best plan for a given SQL statement. Cost can never be used to compare two different SQL statements to determine which one is better; i.e you can have a query with very high cost that is faster and uses less resources than a query that has a low cost.

if the query is as fast as splitting it in two, then leave it as one SQL (1 less round trip to do).

Comment: I (quite surprisingly) gained a better understanding about cost nature and optimizer actions after I took an AI class, lol

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion depends if your db allows parallelism in queries.

If you can, you should run the query in the second way: cost is the same, but you get the result faster.

For example, sqlserver allow you to run parallel query, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178065%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

In oracle, instance, it's explained [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/o40parallel-092275.html).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should test **both** scenarios (one query , cost 100 and two queries, cost 40 + 60) ... try each scenario at least the number of executions your queries would execute in a hour or even a day, remember to apply a alter system flush (buffer cache and shared pool) between the test on each scenarios...